# Why is yum trying to go through a proxy and other strange behaviors?

Tags: yum, proxy

I occasionally setup an SSH tunnel proxy to make it seem like I'm using the internet from another location.  I set it up with:

```
ssh -D 8080 <remote host>
```

and the use the gnome shell Network settings dialog to set the proxy to `http://localhost:8080`.

Currently the proxy is set to None, and my `ssh` connection is disconnected.

My internet browsing is working fine.  However **I cannot use `yum`**:

```
[root@Eiger yum.repos.d]# yum update
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit
http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl
#7 - "Failed connect to localhost:8080; Connection refused"
Trying other mirror.
   <repeated 9 more times>

 One of the configured repositories failed (Adobe Systems Incorporated),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
        just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
        --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable adobe-linux-x86_64

     4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=adobe-linux-x86_64.skip_if_unavailable=true

failure: repodata/repomd.xml from adobe-linux-x86_64: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
http://linuxdownload.adobe.com/linux/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] curl
#7 - "Failed connect to localhost:8080; Connection refused"
   <repeated 9 more times>
```

If I disable the `adobe-linux` repo, then it simply says:

```
[root@Eiger yum.repos.d]# yum update
Loaded plugins: langpacks, refresh-packagekit


 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

     1. Contact the upstream for the repository and get them to fix the problem.

     2. Reconfigure the baseurl/etc. for the repository, to point to a working
        upstream. This is most often useful if you are using a newer
        distribution release than is supported by the repository (and the
        packages for the previous distribution release still work).

     3. Disable the repository, so yum won't use it by default. Yum will then
        just ignore the repository until you permanently enable it again or use
        --enablerepo for temporary usage:

            yum-config-manager --disable <repoid>

     4. Configure the failing repository to be skipped, if it is unavailable.
        Note that yum will try to contact the repo. when it runs most commands,
        so will have to try and fail each time (and thus. yum will be be much
        slower). If it is a very temporary problem though, this is often a nice
        compromise:

            yum-config-manager --save --setopt=<repoid>.skip_if_unavailable=true

Cannot retrieve metalink for repository: fedora/19/x86_64. Please verify its path and try again
```

It's weird that **it doesn't know the name of the repository that is failing** the second time.  It's also weird that **it doesn't try any of the other repositories that I have configured** (fedora, fedora-updates, google-chrome, google-talkplugin, insync, intellinuxgraphics, rpmfusion-free, rpmfusion-free-updates, rpmfusion-nonfree, rpmfusion-nonfree-updates).

This has been working for over a year and I haven't touched `/etc/yum*`.

---

I put my computer to sleep and woke it up a day later.  **Now everything is working as normal.**  I have no explanation for the behavior seen yesterday but I can no longer reproduce it.

Comment: you should update env variables HTTP_PROXY, HTTPS_PROXY, FTP_PROXY if you are using under proxy or set these variable globally.like export http_proxy=http://<remote host>:<port>

Comment: I am not using it under a proxy, but it is somewhat behaving as if I am.  These environment variables are currently empty.

Comment: can you wget or curl something from internet?

Comment: Since disabling your proxy, have you executed `yum clean all`?

Answer (score 2):

I'd confirm that my YUM config file, `/etc/yum.conf` does not contain any `proxy` definitions ala:

```
[main]
proxy=http://localhost:8080
proxy_username=put_proxy_user_name_here
proxy_password=put_proxy_user_password_here
```

Also make sure that none of the other `.conf` files under `/etc/yum.repo.d/*` also do not have any mentions of the proxy details.

I would also debug the issue further by making use of `yum`'s verbose feature:

```
$ yum -v ....
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing the cache resolved it

```
rm -Rf /var/cache
```

and make a new folder

```
mkdir /var/cache
```

This worked for me.

Comment: shouldn't the *R* be lower-case?